# (MySQL) How to insert queries into function without DELIMITER statement?

Tags: mysql, database, function, delimiter, rdbms

Evening.

I'm trying to create a raw function w/o `DELIMITER`, but I can't insert queries under the `RETURNS` keyword.

This is my based function from a tutorial:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fx_sample;
CREATE FUNCTION fx_sample(str VARCHAR(10), idx INT)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
    RETURN CONCAT(str, ', ', idx) ;

SELECT fx_sample("Hi, Reddit", 2);
```

Try 1:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fx_raw;
CREATE FUNCTION fx_raw(str VARCHAR(20), idx INT)
    RETURNS INT
    DECLARE count;
    SET count = CONCAT(LENGTH(str), idx);
    RETURN count;
```

Try 2:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fx_raw2;
CREATE FUNCTION fx_raw2(str VARCHAR(20), idx INT)
    RETURNS INT
        BEGIN
            DECLARE str_length;
            SET str_length = LENGTH(str);
            RETURN str_length + idx;
        END
```

Is inserting queries under the `RETURNS` keyword unavailable?

Comment: And why? You need to change the delimiter!

Comment: @juergend Simply for testing. I'm learning MySQL right now, so I just wanted to know if it was possible or not.

Comment: Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks. I thought it was possible to write the rest of queries into function like the other programming did no matter the delimiter exists or not.